# iOS: Programmatically get stats provided in Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I hope everybody here know that iOS provides detailed file-system statistics in Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage. Is it possible to get such **per-app** stats programmatically?

**Update:**

I discovered some private APIs:

Library: Preferences

Classes: PSUsageBundleManager and PSUsageBundleApp

`-[PSUsageBundleManager allUsageBundleApps]` provides apps.
And the app has propety
`@property (assign,nonatomic) float totalSize`
Unfortunately, this api not working on my iphone, throwing Cocoa error 257.

Comment: have you found a way to retrieve these stats yet ?